# Calculate discount

Tags: apex, batch

In this batch apex class i want to apply discount to the students. If student is **male** then we can apply discount 10%. If student is **female** then we can apply discount 20%

**The above is the code that i tried**

```
public class discount_bb implements database.batchable<sobject>{
    
    public database.querylocator start(database.batchableContext bc){
        string s = 'SELECT Student_Id__c, Name, Gender__c, Fee_paid__c, Discount__c FROM Student__c';
        return database.getquerylocator(s);
    }
    
    public void execute(database.batchableContext de, list<Student__c> a){
        for(Student__c x:a ){
            if(x.Gender__c == 'Male'){
                x.Discount__c = '10%';
            }
            else if(x.Gender__c == 'Female'){
                x.Discount__c = '20%';
            }
        }
        update a;
    }
    
    public void finish(database.batchableContext fg){
        system.debug('Finish:::!!!');
    }
}
```

The fields that i have in custom sobject name **student__c** is

- Age__c
- Courses__c
- Discount__c
- Fee_paid__c
- Gender__c
- Joining_Date__c
- Mobile_Number__c
- Nationality__c
- Status__c
- Student_Id__c
- Today_Date__c

I didn't know what to put in the code. I gave the discount text field 10% and 20% discount, Tell me how i can do with the formula to calculate discount

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! How exactly can we help you? Why don't you just use formula fields? What's the actual requirement here? If you haven't yet, please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. After that, [edit] your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve, specifically, so we can help you.

Comment: I want to use formula field. Please explain how to calculate discount in formula field

Comment: If you're new to pretty much any part or feature of Salesforce, the best place to start learning about it is going to be https://trailhead.salesforce.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it

1. Use Formula Field
2. Use workflow (basis your business requirement whether on insert or insert and update)

If you choose to do it with formula field, create a formula field with formula return type as Percent
[image: Formula Return Type]
and click next
Click on Advanced Tab on next screen
[image: Advanced Formula]
and enter this
CASE(Gender__c,'MALE',10,20)

Save the field

If you choose to do it with **Workflow** create a Filed on Object of type percent and then create a workflow with evaluation criteria as **Created and Every time it's edited**

In the Rule Criteria put
**ISCHANGED(Gender__C)**

Add a **Workflow Action of type Field Update**

And in Workflow Action select **Use a Formula to set a new value** and in fomula type
**CASE(Gender__c,'MALE',10,20)**

Comment: Thank you very much Sir